# Trying to write a simple script for work in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'll start off by saying that I have no experience in JavaScript. What I've "learned" for this script is from 10 minutes of googling.

I have two form fields, named 'Section Width' (SW) and 'Insp Unit Width' (IUW) that are whole numbers. I'm trying to get IUW to equal SW if SW is less than or equal to 40. If SW is greater than 40 I need IUW to be half of SW to the next whole number. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
var SW = this.getField("Section Width").value;
var IUW = this.getField("Insp Unit Width");
if (SW <= 40){
    IUW = SW;
}, else {
    IUW = 0.5*SW;
}
```

Can someone please briefly educate me or point me to where I can learn how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const SW = this.getField("Section Width").value;

const IUW = (SW <= 40) ? SW : Math.ceil(0.5*SW);
```

Since you're ignoring the value of the IUW field, you don't need to do the `IUW = this.getField("Insp Unit Width")` part. Although, perhaps you need a reference to that field because you're going to update the field later... If that's the case, try:

```js
const SW = this.getField("Section Width").value;

const IUW = (SW <= 40) ? SW : Math.ceil(0.5*SW);

const IUWField = this.getField("Insp Unit Width");

IUWField.value = IUW;
```

Comment: Would your 2nd script actually update the IUW field? I'm not getting any result when I enter values into the SW field.

Comment: @Max I'm not an expert in Acrobat, and you've not said what you've done to try and get the javascript to be called. What is triggering the javascript, and are you sure it's being called? It's impossible to debug this situation if there is not a full example of what you're trying

Comment: my apologies, I should have been more detailed. I am entering the script under the IUW text field properties. Within the properties menu options there is a 'Calculate' tab and within that window there is the option for 'Custom calculation script'.

If I go to edit that custom option I'm presented with the ability to create or edit a JavaScript that will essentially calculate a value for the field. I've used simpler options in this calculate window that have worked, so I was assuming this custom option would work as well.

Would it be better to ask this question in the adobe forums?

Comment: @Max sorry, I can tell you how javascript works, but I don't know how Acrobat works